# Image stored in mysql (longblob) wont show

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, blob

I stored an image in my mysql database but hower i try to display in in my php page it doesn't show.

I tried a couple forum ideas without success

View :

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
    echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($gebruiker->profileImage)."' alt='profielfoto'>";
    ?>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$this->load->model('gebruiker_model');
$data['gebruiker'] = $this->gebruiker_model->get($id);
```

Model:

```
function get($id)
{
   $this->db->where('id', $id);
   $query = $this->db->get('gebruiker');
   return $query->row();
}
```

Inspect:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="profielfoto"></div>
```

I would like the image to show stored in my db but it does not display.
the images are PNG.

Comment: where is image tag?

Comment: I added it in the code i made a smaal change

Comment: where is its path you need to set path then image name then its extension everything is missing

Comment: could you give an example? a path to what? the image is in my database.

Comment: How would you display the image the database contains a binairy code

Comment: what is your image field database type? TEXT, VARCHAR?

Answer (score 0):

use `base64_encode`

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
    echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($gebruiker->profileImage)."' alt='profielfoto'>";
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Im getting an image icon with the alt next to it but still  no image

Comment: try `image/jpeg` or `image/jpg`

Comment: Same result i also added the inspect of the view

Answer (score 0):

**when you are inserting the blob file use file_get_contents() function.**

and know more about this you can refer to this 
 link : [Image upload to MySQL database blob in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621271/image-upload-to-mysql-database-blob-in-codeigniter)

Comment: I did you can view this right here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302664/mysql-insert-image-in-php-the-post-functions-return-0